# TypeError: Spread syntac requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, editorjs

I recently updated my Cordova app and started getting this error on iOS from the editor.js package. The package works on all browsers, just seeing the issue on mobile. I inquired with the editorjs community and they believe it's a Cordova issue. Does anyone have any ideas of what might have caused this or any ideas on how I should go about debugging. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you're passing null or undefined (which is not enumerable).